Favicon doesn't work on second page, but works on first page
I have a default.html file with the following line:
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
It works well on the first page, but it doesn't work on the second page.
I tried moving the <head> section from default.html to the second page, but the issue with the favicon not working on the second page persists.

You have to link the icon on every page - thats for sure. Can you show us any code that you've already written? Some insight you know - else we can't really help!

Andis the second page in a sub directory under the first page?

You can check my repo with all code - https://github.com/Syrinca/Syrinca.github.io

Second page in inwekpuhien folder
